# How to get the item reference with getItemAtPosition in Android?

Tags: android

I’m using the default Navigation drawer proposed by Android Studio IDE, with the default list item, and I want to get the i item from the list View, I’ve tried to do this `TextView txt = (TextView) mDrawerListView.getItemAtPosition(3);` but the app crashed in the lunch. I want to know what is the error and if there is others solutions.

**My Adapter :**

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
            new String[] {
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
                    getString(R.string.title_section4),
                    getString(R.string.title_section5),
                    getString(R.string.title_section6)}) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
           // textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_grey));

            //To Set the icones
            Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spots);
            Drawable image2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sessions);

            TextView txt = (TextView) mDrawerListView.getItemAtPosition(3);
            txt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( image2, null, null, null);


            return textView;
        }
    });
```

Thanks

**Update : it is correct ?**

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
            new Info[] {
                    new Info(getString(R.string.title_section1),  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spots)),
                    new Info(getString(R.string.title_section2),  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sessions)),
                    new Info(getString(R.string.title_section3),  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar)),
                    new Info(getString(R.string.title_section4),  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clubs_pages)),
                    new Info(getString(R.string.title_section5),  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cv)),
                    new Info(getString(R.string.title_section6),  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cv_life))
                         }
```

Comment: `getItemAtPosition` returns the element of the dataset at position. Casting it to TextView will make your app crash with `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Ok, so how can i get the text of this element ?

Comment: `String fourthString = (String)getItem(3)`

Comment: i want to get the TextView to set the function `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`

Comment: you have already. The textview you have to handle with is `extView textView = (TextView) super.getView`

Comment: Yes but how can i get every item in the list view ? Because i will set the same icon for all the items !

Comment: getView is called for every item in the ListView

Comment: Yes sir, but i want to get each item seperated to set the right icon for it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of having an ArrayAdapter, if you want to customize text and icon for every child of the ListView, I would rather use a bean object, called `Info`, for instance, that  contains those information 
(`ArrayAdapter<Info>` ). For instance

```
class Info {

  String mText;
  Drawable mDrawable;
  public Info(String text, Drawable dra) {
     mText = text;
     mDrawable = dra;
  }
}
```

and the Adapter:

```
new ArrayAdapter<Info>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
            new Info[] {
            new Info(getString(R.string.title_section1),  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.first_drawable),
// other elements
```

and in getView

```
TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
Info info = (Info) getItem(position);
textView.setText(info.mText);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( info.mDrawable, null, null, null);
```

please check for typo

Comment: can you see wath i've added in the the body of the question

Comment: `new ArrayAdapter<String>` must be new `ArrayAdapter<Info>`